Как запустить ahk через python3?
Пишу код и мне надо запустить ahk скрипт через python прям в коде, скоко не пытался не как ни сделать, перепробовал все способы, помогите плиз

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Там вроде как библиотека для питона была

Для интеграции Python и AutoHotkey есть библиотеки. Например AHK.
Установка:
pip install ahk

Использование:
from ahk import AHK
ahk = AHK()
script_path = r'C:\Path\To\myscript.ahk'
ahk.run_script(script_path)

Или:
from ahk import AHK
ahk = AHK()
my_script = '''\
MouseMove, 100, 100
; etc...
'''

ahk.run_script(my_script)

Документация есть по ссылке
